# Visual Studio 2015 halts when clicking the Authors link

Tags: visual-studio-2015, skype-for-business

When I use Visual Studio 2015 (fully updated) and I click the `Authors` auto-link above the method signatures, it freezes (but doesn't crash) and I start seeing `Microsoft Visual Studio is Busy` notifications, and the `Skype for Business`-application starts popping up at seeming random intervals, for no apparent reason.

Any unsaved changes are lost (!).

[image: The authors link]
[image: The notification]

It goes on like that until I kill the `devenv.exe` process.

Is there any way to fix this, maybe by just showing a list of author names - or worst case just disable the feature so I can't accidently click the link again.

Comment: can you use process explorer from sys internals to find out more on what the process is doing and try to contact Visual studio team from twitter

Comment: I wouldn't know what to look for in the process explorer. If I had a guide, sure. Also I don't really like twitter.

Comment: get processid of devenv.exe from task manager and launch process explorer and try filtering processid.you could see entire call stack

Comment: some times twitter responses are faster

Comment: I recommend to log it here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html. You can also see if there is anything in the ActivityLog https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241272.aspx and you could turn on extended logging in skype for business: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2604292/how-to-collect-log-files-from-office-communicator,-lync,-and-skype-for-business-client.

Comment: this happens in VS2017 as well. have you learned anything about this problem @Gertsen?

Comment: Sorry, nothing new to report. We switched to Azure DevOps instead of on-premise TFS about two years ago. I haven't noticed this in a very long time, I pretty much forgot about it. Not sure if the problem was solved by switching to DevOps or I just stopped hitting the links by mistake.

Comment: I have this problem - it brings up my SkypeForBusiness - and eventally returns control after about 120 seconds